# Keep local and production composer.json files in sync?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I am working on a large project with a lot of git repositories. I can easily keep them in sync like this:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

```
"repositories": [
    { "type": "path",  "url": "../another-component" },
    { "type": "path",  "url": "../yet-another-component" }
]
```

If I run composer this will create a symbolic link inside my vendor folder for each repository provided. This way whenever I update one of the repositories outside my main `app` repository changes will be reflected immediately.

This is a perfect local development solution but on production I would just like to have a composer file that points to the online Github repositories and pull the repositories from Github.

Of course this composer file would look a bit different since the types would be set to `vcs` and the url's would point to Github instead of being relative paths.

How do people do this for local/production setups? Do you just maintain 2 separate composer files, one for local development and another for production?

This would mean whenever I add another repository to my codebase I have to remember to update it in 2 places or my entire codebase breaks down.

Comment: I push dependencies to remote vcs all the time and use single composer.json. Don't see why it is a problem.

Comment: @AlexBlex the `require` section of my `composer.json` stays exactly the same, so the dependencies themselves stay exactly the same. Locally I want my url's to point to my filesystem though. In productinn I want to point my url's to an actual Github repo.

Comment: I have also just found this thread where a very similar issue is being discussed: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6158 This topic has also come up multiple times in the `issues` section of composer now that I am looking into it. I was just hoping somebody could provide a cleaner solution for this then what is currently available.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't believe convenience of editing multiple repos simultaneously worths risk of messing up with versions jumping between branches. Especially if there are several people working on the same codebase, and resolving merge conflicts is a daily routine.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -2):

Since it seems your components are already hosted online, I would recommend to just let composer pull them down from Github and manage them like any other dependency, be it from development or production.

Comment: They are composer packages, otherwise this wouldn't work in the first place since composer is looking for a `composer.json` file in those directories. And I already have managed them with composer this question is about managing them locally vs on production. In production you would point to a Github repo instead of using a relative path.

Comment: My mistake, didn't realise the "local path" option still required the target to be a composer package; I've edited my answer. May I ask what's the reason behind not letting composer just pull your components from Github when developing, as if you were on production?

Comment: If you work in 10+ repositories and quickly making changes between all of them because the entirety of these repositories make up your code, you absolutely do want to to push and pull each single repository all the time. You want the changes to be reflected in your main `app` repository instantly. Composer's `path` option does this by symlinking other repositories into the vendor directory of your main application.

Comment: I see, it looks like the issue might be the architecture of the project itself since its components seem quite tightly coupled yet require a lot of frequent changes, but it's probably too late to address innit. Anyway, I would advise against attempting to maintain 2 different composer.json files, doesn't seem worth the hassle. Any way you could set up your project on production the same way you did on development maybe?